# SSH access to Azure for Rails deployment with Capistrano

Tags: azure, ssh

I am trying to deploy a Rails website to an Azure VM with Capistrano.
To do this I need a SSH key setup. Currently I can connect to the VM while using this:

```
ssh -i ./mykey.key myuser@mysite.cloudapp.net -p22
```

But when trying to connect like this (as Capistrano will do:

```
ssh myuser@mysite.cloudapp.net
```

It denies access: `Permission denied (publickey).`. What do I need to do to make this work? I assume I need to add my SSH key to Azure, but it seems not to work like this as e.g. Github allows to add SSH keys?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the same key for Azure. 
OpenSSH private keys are directly readable by the openssl utility. The following command will take an existing SSH private key (id_rsa in the example below) and create the .pem public key that is needed for Azure:

```
# openssl req -x509 -key ~/.ssh/id_rsa -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -out myCert.pem
```

The myCert.pem file is the public key that may then be used to provision a Linux virtual machine on Azure. During provisioning the .pem file will be translated into an openssh compatible public key and placed in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

After the VM is provisioned, you can get the SSH endpoint by running the following command:

```
azure vm endpoint list <vm-name>
```

you can read more on [using SSH with Linux on Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-use-ssh-key/)

Also, here is a post on [How to deploy a Ruby on Rails Web application to a Windows Azure VM using Capistrano](https://milaptech.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/deploy-a-ruby-on-rails-web-application-to-a-windows-azure-vm-using-capistrano/)